# How to convert binary saved output in Torch between different Luajit versions?

Tags: file, torch, luajit

I save a argument into a ".nn" file with Torch.save() under Luajit 2.1.0, 
when I try to load the saved file from another machine with Luajit 2.0.4, using Torch.load(), it shows "/share/apps/torch/20160408/bin/luajit: /share/apps/torch/20160408/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:301: Failed to load function from bytecode: (binary): cannot load incompatible bytecode"

I want to ask, is there a way to convert the saved file under Luajit 2.1.0 to a readable file with Luajit 2.0.4?  It takes very long time to run the program on Luajit 2.0.4 machine, so I am thinking about how to convert file type directly. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is not a problem between incompatible versions of LuaJIT but that the other machine is using PUC Rio Lua instead of LuaJIT. What `lua -v` returns in the other machine?